# Blurry edges when using "corrplot" package in R

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I'm using corrplot in R to plot the correlation matrrix. For some reason, the edges of the circles in the plot seems missing some pixels. The plot overall looks very rough. Please see the graph I plotted:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZPca.png)

But the example I followed shows the plot is supposed to be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p6ty.png)

My initial guess was dpi and scaling issue because I use a 4K display. I tried changing the resolution and size of the plots but it doesn't work.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What output device are you using?

Comment: Do you get the blurred edges if you save the plot as a pdf?

Comment: The issue you're seeing is most likely a problem with raster displays versus vector displays/formats. If you save it as a vector format (e.g., svg, pdf), then the ratcheted edges should disappear. This is related to several other artifacts that can appear in R's plot windows that are not actually in the plot, just artifacts of the pixelated display.